# Change cultureinfo and get correct resx translation

Tags: c#, resx, cultureinfo

Im trying to use the following code to get translation from my swedish resx but it will only return the english translation from my default resx. I have the translations in both file with the exact same key. I call this from a command line c# program. Anyone know why it will not translate?

```
public String GetString(String resxPackageName, String xmlKey)
{            
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE", false);
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("MyPackage.CustomerPortal.Followup", this.GetType().Assembly);
    return rm.GetString("CurrentPriceTagTranslation");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you don't specify a culture in *GetString* method it will use the *CurrentUICulture* of the calling thread, if you change it everything should work.

Comment: Worked great thank you! Follow up q if you have time: Will this be possible to use in a web application where different users select different languages? So that all users get there requested language and there is no interference?

Comment: @Marthin: Yes it will work: Just set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture in your controller's c'tor (assuming MVC) to make sure every loaded resource will be based on user's preferred culture.